# remove the alert that pops up when calling from iOS app using telprompt://

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make a call from my iOS app, and after the user is done calling, i need him to come back on the same app screen from where he made the call. if i use the following code

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@"999999999"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

i achieve what i want, but get an unwanted alert confirming if the user wants to make a call or not. I don't want this.

If i use the code

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"999999999"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

i do not get the alert, but i do not get back to my app screen too..!!

Is there a way where i do not get the alert while making the call and get back to the app screen after making the call?? please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do otherwise, those are the two possibilities. `telprompt` with alert and callback or `tel` with not coming back and no alert.

Comment: I have read in a lot of places that using telprompt may lead to app removal from the store in future. SO im really confused how to achieve both things that i need.. are there any third party apis that i can use?

Comment: I've heard both, I think you should try with and be prepared to do without but it's more a question of who is testing your app at Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If the users leaves the app to make a phone call, there's no way you can return to your app after it. Your app is backgrounded, and the phone app is foregrounded.